# MS-Access SSPI error with .adp

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sspi

I have an old Access project (.adp) that was tied to a SQL Server database using integrated authentication. The .adp is only used this time of year. Since its last use, the SQL Server has been virtualized and patched to current. When I try to open the .adp, it gives me a "Cannot generate SSPI context" error. I got this with another .mdb and just remapped the linked tables through ODBC with a SQL Server login (integrated authentication is not a requirement). However, with this .adp file, just about all the options are greyed out. For example, Linked Table Manager and ODBC Database buttons are greyed out. I can't see any tables, nor apparently link or import any. Is there a way to remove integrated authentication from an .adp project? Or can I convert the database to an .mdb (exporting objects appears greyed out as well)?

NOTE: This is a limited use database with few users on its way out, so I'm very open to "creative" workarounds that don't require me rebuilding the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Please, review the following:

- Check that SQL Server allow integrated authentication
- Your machine (where you open the adp project) and the server are both in the same
  domain.

That error is typical when the client machine belongs to another domain or not belongs to any domain.